# WPF Bind to an ObserVableCollection found inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

Hy Everyone!

My situation so far:

- I have an observable collection ("PipesSystemList") which is made up of "DataBaseSystem" objects:

```
public static ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem> PipesSystemList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>();
```

```
public class DatabaseSystem
{
    public string System { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get;set;}

}
```

- I successfully bind this collection to my combobox as it follows and everything works perfectly:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainView,Path=DataContext.PipesSystemList}" 
          Padding="2" Margin="5 0 5 0" Width="70" Height="20" 
          Foreground ="#F1F1F1" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyleDark}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:DatabaseSystem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding System}" Foreground="#F1F1F1" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                          Command="{Binding ElementName=MainView, Path=DataContext.PipeTabChosenSystemChangedCommand }"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

What I wanted to achieve: Because I have multiple equipment type, I wanted to have all the necesarry collection in one place. so I created a dictionary:

```
var SystemTabLists = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>>()
{
    {"Document List",new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>()},
    {"Pipes",new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>()},
    {"Valves",new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>()},
    {"Sensors",new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>()},
    {"Vessels",new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>()},
    {"Heat Exchangers",new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>()},
    {"Filters",new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>()},
    {"Other Equipment",new ObservableCollection<DatabaseSystem>()}
};
```

After this, I tried to bind the combobox to the collection belonging to the Pipes (I successfully managed to fill up the collection with the right elements, so the data I need is there):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainView,Path=DataContext.SystemTabLists[Pipes]}" 
          Padding="2" Margin="5 0 5 0" Width="70" Height="20" 
          Foreground ="#F1F1F1" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyleDark}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:DatabaseSystem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding System}" Foreground="#F1F1F1" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                          Command="{Binding ElementName=MainView, Path=DataContext.PipeTabChosenSystemChangedCommand }"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Unfortunately this is not working.
When I debug the code and I turn on tracing for bindings I receive this:
"*BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SystemTabLists[Pipes]*"

Could someone help me what am I doing wrong? Or point out if this is not possible to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use CompositeCollection and/or DataTemplate

Comment: Sry it is only a hobby project of mine. What do you mean specifically when you say "use DataTemplate" Am I not using it already? or incorrectly?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-a-compositecollection

Comment: This all works in a new project I just whiped out for this case which indicates you are not sharing the whole thing.